# How to remove extra spacing before the title in streamlit?

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I've built a basic streamlit app. I am would like to know if there is a way to remove the extra space above the title. In the attached image you can see a noticeable gap between address bar and title

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by injecting some css inside the view:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

padding_top = 0

st.markdown(f"""
    <style>
        .reportview-container .main .block-container{{
            padding-top: {padding_top}rem;
        }}
    </style>""",
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

st.title("My Next Best Actions")

st.sidebar.text_input("foo")
```

[image: Lower padding on top of the title]]

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.streamlit/config.toml` place these two lines:

```
[ui]
hideTopBar = true
```

In your main code, add following lines of code:

```
    st.markdown("""
            <style>
                .block-container{
                     padding-top: 25px;
                 }
            </style>
                """, 
            unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything for me?