# Position first widget higher up

Tags: html, css, streamlit

In `streamlit`, I am positioning the very first `image logo` like this:

```
with col1:
    st.image("logo.jpg", width = 300)
```

Problem is, the default first placement of a `widget` is too far low for my taste. So in this image:

[image]

The first `element` "NYC Ridesharing Data" is too low.

How do I move it up?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69115106/how-to-remove-extra-spacing-before-the-title-in-streamlit/69584839#69584839

Comment: Unfortunately, that appears only to affect st.Title. I need the very first widget, regardless of type, in my case an st.Image, to move up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `st.markdown` with `unsafe_allow_html=True` and modify the style of the component responsible for the padding at the top of the page. Css-wise, you need to set the `padding-top` of the class `block-container` to 0.

```py
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

st.markdown("""
    <style>
        .block-container {padding-top: 0 !important;}
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True,
)

col1, col2 = st.columns([5, 3])

with col1:
    st.title("Some cute cat")
    st.slider("Select hour of pickup")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg", width=300)

with col2:
    st.markdown("Some text and a cute picture of a dog")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/dog.jpg")

with st.container():
    st.markdown("Here is a container")
```

It gives:

[image: No padding at the top]